# labelling line features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling, maplex

I am working with arcmap 10.2.2. 
I would like to label features in maps which I create with data driven pages. I have one ddp layer and another layer with the labels. The layer with the label features have map nummers (a field in the attribute table) according to the map numbers in the ddp. Now I only want those features to be labelled if the map number (on the dpp map) corresponds with the map nummer in the attribute table. Some maps have for example six line features, but only three should be labeled because in the attribute table only those three features have the corresponding map number. Now It labels all line features but the maps overlap so I do not want that.
Hope I made myself clear and someone knows How to do this. I tried already with the maplex label engine..

P.s. if possible NOT to difficult python scripting

Answer (score 2):

You could use a page definition query to turn features on and off:

Add another copy of the layer, and apply desired labeling to it. Then apply a page definition query to that layer so that only features that match the map number are shown.

[This](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39495) knowledge base article should help with the concept

Comment: That worked out almost as I want. Only problem now is that the extent that is used to create the maps should be the one with the highest value otherwise not all features show on the map. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by this. Can you provide more detail?